# VBA Script takes 1000X longer to run when a second work book isopen (yet is not used)

Tags: vba, excel

All -

I am writing a script to help me process some data.  I am testing the code below in a workbook, called "smallWorkbook" that has only a couple thousand rows of data.  I run the code **from** smallWorkbook **on data that is in** smallWorkbook.  The code runs in .06 seconds (after selecting ranges).

I also have a 50 MB workbook with hundres of thousands of rows across 30 worksheets called "largeWorkbook".  If I simply have largeWorkbook open at the same time as smallWorkbook, and run the code exactly as described above, the code takes 60 seconds to run!

Can someone describe why running the code ***from*** smallWorkbook on data ***in*** smallWorkbook ***while*** largeWorkBook is open would slow the run time so badly?  Does it have something to do with the way my code is written or my ranges are qualified? I am not so good with these subtleties.

Thanks for reading.

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit
'*************************************************
'*************************************************
Sub MinInGroup()
'MIN IN GROUP
'Use this sub to add a table that contains unique IDs as rows
'and min quantities for each group that corresponds to unique ID
'Table is added to worksheet named sandbox" hard-coded in this routine

'Future work:
'1)add ability to selct from another workbook to create
'standalone app (selecting a range in another wrkbk requires custom user form, spaces in wrkbk or sheet
'names makes trouble).
'2) dont hard code headers
'3) array sizing - 1000 OK for this use case
'4) Remove lines that get minimum of columnn next to one choosen as this is not nominal case

'EXAMPLE:
'calling MinInGroup on range GRP range and QTY range:
' GRP|QTY
' AA | 5
' AA | 9
' AA | 2
' BB | 1
' BB | 5
' CC | 26
' CC | 70

' Returns

' GRP|MIN
' AA | 2
' BB | 1
' CC | 26

Dim grpNameRng As Range 'range containing sub groups (ie AA,BB,CC)
Dim valRng As Range 'range containing values to find min on
Set grpNameRng = Application.InputBox("Select group range (no headers)", "Select Group Range", Type:=8)
Set valRng = Application.InputBox("Select value range (no headers)", "Select Value Range", Type:=8)

'***************************************
'For dev only, delete when done
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer
'***************************************

'Make sure same length
If grpNameRng.Count <> valRng.Count Then
    MsgBox ("Ranges must have same number of elements. Exiting.")
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim grpStartIndex As Long           'row index of start of new group
Dim grpNameArry(1000) As Variant    'Array of unique grps. In EX above grpNameArry = {AA, BB, CC}
Dim minValArry(1000) As Variant     'Array of min vals each group. minValArry = {2, 1, 26}

'Turn off screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
j = 1
grpStartIndex = 1
grpNameArry(j) = grpNameRng(1)
For i = 1 To grpNameRng.Count
    If (grpNameRng(i)) <> grpNameRng(i + 1) Then    'i is end of current group
        'calc MIN val for current group
        minValArry(j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(valRng.Cells(grpStartIndex), valRng.Cells(i)))
        grpStartIndex = i + 1
        j = j + 1
        grpNameArry(j) = grpNameRng(i + 1)

    End If
Next i

'Write results to a range in "sandbox" sheet
With Worksheets("sandbox")
'Write headers
    .Range("D3").Value = "LC"
    .Range("D3").Font.Bold = True
    .Range("E3").Value = "Min Msy"
    .Range("E3").Font.Bold = True
    .Range("F3").Value = "Min Msu"
    .Range("F3").Font.Bold = True
    For i = 1 To j - 1
        .Range(.Cells(3 + i, 5), .Cells(3 + i, 5)).Value = minValArry(i)
        .Range(.Cells(3 + i, 4), .Cells(3 + i, 4)).Value = grpNameArry(i)
    Next i

End With

'Turn off screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'***************************************
'For dev only, delete when done
'Determine how many seconds code took to run
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
MsgBox ("Code ran in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds.")
'***************************************

End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Application.Calculation = xlManualCalculation` at top of code and see what happens.

Comment: @ScottCraner - beat you by 1/2 millisecond again!

Comment: To go a little more into it, your other worksheet probably has a lot of volatile functions and every time the current workbook causes a recalc all of the volatile functions will re calc.  My guess is that the other worksheet has a lot of INDIRECT, OFFSET and/or ADDRESS functions in it.

Comment: No luck, same result. I have already changed the calculation type to manual thru GUI and turned off calc before save.

Comment: Side question, doesn't Worksheets("sheetname") default to the open workbook?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this is fully qualified or not... `Range(valRng.Cells(grpStartIndex), valRng.Cells(i))` I guess you could add Worksheet("name").Range --- not sure that it matters though...